# Grouping data in comma separated format

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called SampleData which looks like this:

```
 col1    col2     
    1       a       
    1       b       
    1       c      
    2       d       
    2       e
    3       f
```

I need the data in the below format:

```
col1    col2     
1       a,b,c           
2       d,e       
3       f
```

Is there a way of doing this using CTE as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) if you are using `SQL Server 2005` and above.

```
SELECT
     [col1],
     STUFF(
         (SELECT ',' + [col2]
          FROM Table1
          WHERE [col1] = a.[col1]
          FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, '')  AS col2
FROM Table1 AS a
GROUP BY [col1]
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5558/1)

Comment: thanks,Is there a way of doing this using CTE as in my original requirement this makes very slow

Answer (score 1):

I think this is also useful to you.

[Comma Seprate Value](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1260952-338-1.aspx#bm1470333)